# ANDROID_ID invoke on a null object error Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new in android app development. I have been trying to build an app with Firebase email and password auth and also trying to save the `ANDROID_ID` of the phone in the Firebase database during the sign-up process.

But whenever I'm opening the SignUp Activity, the app shuts down and displays the following error in the Logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.rimikri.smartpedi/com.rimikri.smartpedi.SignUpActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.ContentResolver
>   android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object
>   reference

This is my SignUp activity:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextName;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        User user = new User(
                            name,
                            androidId
                        );

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                                    //
                                }
                            });

                    } else {
                        //
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The class `User` that I have is:

```
public class User {
    public String name;


    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

How should I get the ANDROID_ID here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your `androidId` inside **`onCreate()`** method

Try this

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextName;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public String androidId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        User user = new User(
                            name,
                            androidId
                        );

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                                    //
                                }
                            });

                    } else {
                        //
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```